# Why is $\nabla f({\bf p}) =\sum_i \left( 2{\bf p} - 2{\bf p}_i \right) $?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If

$$
f({\bf p}) = \sum_i \left({\bf p}\cdot {\bf p} - 2{\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}_i + {\bf p}_i\cdot {\bf p}_i\right)
$$

Why is the gradient of $f(p)$ equal to

$
\nabla f({\bf p}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf p}}\sum_i \left({\bf p}\cdot {\bf p} - 2{\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}_i + {\bf p}_i\cdot {\bf p}_i \right) 
=\sum_i \left( 2{\bf p} - 2{\bf p}_i \right) $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in components, consider the first term for example

$$
{\bf p}\cdot {\bf p} = p_1p_1 + p_2p_2 + \cdots
$$

So the gradient of this term is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}}{\partial p_1} &=& 2p_1 \\
\frac{\partial {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}}{\partial p_2} &=& 2p_2 \\
&\vdots &
\end{eqnarray}

or in general

$$
\frac{\partial {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}}{\partial {\bf p}} = 2{\bf p}
$$

Similarly you can prove that

$$
\frac{\partial {\bf p}\cdot {\bf p}_i}{\partial {\bf p}} = {\bf p}_i
$$